# Build dictionary from list comprehension over nested lists

Tags: python

For an input nested list

`[[[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[5,6]], [[7,8], [9,10], [10,10]]]`

I want to build a comprehension that will assemble a nested dictionary **D** such that:

```
D[0] [1] = 2, D[0][3] = 4
D[1] [5] = 6
D[2] [7] = 8, D[2][9] = 10, D[2][10] = 10
```

My dictionary comprehension is the following:

`dict = {k1:{v[0]:v[1]} for k1, sub in enumerate(tg1) for v in sub}`

but there is a problem in that it does not contain every pair.

How do I do this?

Comment: You need nested dictionary comprehensions ot create nested dictionaries.

Comment: Can you show me how the nested dictionary comprehension would work? That's what I wanted to do.

Comment: That is not a list comprehension. List comprehensions *create lists*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use dictionary comprehension, you have to *nest* it. In your approach only one key-value pair gets to your inner dictionary, wherein you actually want *that* part to be a comprehension itself. Something like this would work:

```py
d = {i:{k:v for k,v in sublist} for i, sublist in enumerate(l)}
```

Assuming `l` is your list here.

Answer (score 1):

If you only have these levels of nesting, you can do it with a comprehension. On the other hand if you have more levels, you'll probably need a (recursive) function:

```
D = { i:dict(L) for i,L in enumerate(yourList)}

{0: {1: 2, 3: 4}, 
 1: {5: 6}, 
 2: {7: 8, 9: 10, 10: 10}}

D[0][3] # 4
D[1][5] # 6
```